# Object with 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone explain me why the result of this 2 pieces of code is "2,1"? I don't understand how both the 2 pieces return that result.

```
var grid = [["0,0", "1,0", "2,0"],
            ["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]];
show(grid[1][2]);


var grid = ["0,0", "1,0", "2,0",
            "0,1", "1,1", "2,1"];
show(grid[2 + 1 * 3]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the problem ? In computing 2+1*3 ?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? Both member accesses result in the same value, because your data is structured like that.

Comment: Hey people, we know every SO user knows what happens but there's no need to add more answers !

Comment: This looks like a homework problem for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// A two-dimensional array is like having a table with rows and columns,
// though the first element always starts with "0" (as opposed to 1)

var grid = [
/* column:  0    , 1    , 2
/* row 0 */["0,0", "1,0", "2,0"],
/* row 1 */["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]
];
show(grid[1][2]); // row 1, column 2
```

---

```
// This is just a simple array with elements, again the indexes
// start at 0.

/* index:   0    , 1    ,  2   , 3    , 4    , 5    */
var grid = ["0,0", "1,0", "2,0", "0,1", "1,1", "2,1"];
show(grid[2 + 1 * 3]); // order of operations applies so 2+1*3 is actually:
                       // "2+(1*3)" => "2+3" => "5"
                       // so grid[5] = "2,1"
```

Comment: I +1'ed this answer already before the edit, how do I do +2? :)

Comment: Thanks, now I see that's very easy. I didn't saw that the [1] was about row 1

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in Javascript begins with 0, not 1.

So let's break it down.

`grid[1]` actually points to the second array `["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]`

So then `grid[1][2]` points to the third value in that array, which is `2,1`

As for the second array, accessing `grid[5]` is pointing to the sixth value in the array which is also `2,1`

Answer (score 1):

```
var grid = [["0,0", "1,0", "2,0"],
            ["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]];
```

**grid[1][2]**

Arrays count from 0. So `grid[1]` is the second half of the array and `grid[1][2]` is the 3rd value in the 2nd array.

```
var grid = ["0,0", "1,0", "2,0",
        "0,1", "1,1", "2,1"];
```

**grid[2 + 1 * 3]**

`grid[2 + 1 * 3] === grid[5]`: the 6th value in the array

Answer (score 0):

Because in both cases, the specified index points to the string "2,1"

Remember, javascript arrays use 0-based indexes, so the index 0 is the first thing in the array, the index 1 is the second, and so on,

In the first, the index `[1][2]` points to the second array, the third thing in that array.

In the second, you have 1 array with 6 things, and your index `2 + 1 * 3` evaluates to 5, which is the 6th thing in the array.

Answer (score 0):

what's wrong? in first case it's a 2D array. in second case it's a 1D array. There's just an enter after 3rd element (in second case). that's all

Answer (score 0):

First function: `show(grid[1][2])` outputs the third element of the second array, so `2,1`

And for the second 2 + 1 * 3 = 5 so it shows grid[5]

Comment: That is not a function. -1.

Comment: When I said function I was talking about `show()` not grid. I know that's not a function.

Comment: Aha. But as it currently stands, one can't see that. But I'll lift my downvote.

Comment: My vote is locked, could you edit your answer and let me know so I can undownvote your answer?

Comment: I edited, but don't worry I don't mind the down vote. You are right, my answer was ambiguous :)

Answer (score 0):

What's so difficult about that?

Last select is as result "grid[5]", and this is "2,1".

Answer (score 0):

Enclosing comma separated values in `[` & `]` creates an array, a kind of list.
You can access values in an array by giving an 'index' in brackets after the name of the array. The first item is found under index '0', the second under '1', etc.

Now if you do this:

```
show(grid[1][2]);
```

It first gets the thing on the second position of grid. Hey, it's an array! So we can get the third value of that thing! And the third value of that array is '2,1'. The same for the second sample, it only calculates the index on the fly. 2 + 1*3 = 5, so the sixth array item: "2,1".

Answer (score 0):

Heh, I suppose you missed that the array indexes starting from 0. So the grid[0][0] in first case and the grid[0] in the second case should result in "0,0" and the grid[1][1] in first case is "1,1" and grid[1] in secod case is "1,0" (no surprise now?) :)

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the value of `grid[1]` is the second item in the array, i.e. the array `["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]`, so the value of `grid[1][2]` is the third item in that value, i.e. `"2,1"`.

In the second example, the value of `2 + 1 * 3` is `5`, and `grid[5]` is the sixth element in the array, i.e. `"2,1"`.

The examples shows two different ways of handling two dimensional data in Javascript. If you look at an array as segments of a specific size, that is similar to having an array of arrays, where the sub-arrays are of that specific size.

Answer (score 0):

```
var grid = [["0,0", "1,0", "2,0"],
            ["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"]];
show(grid[1][2]);
```

Array Index Position Always starts from `0` . `grid` is a two dimensional array.

**show(grid[1][2]);**

```
grid[1] == ["0,1", "1,1", "2,1"] //2nd element in the grid array .

grid[1][2] = "2,1"; //3rd element in grid[1] .
```

**show(grid[2 + 1 * 3])**;

```
var grid = ["0,0", "1,0", "2,0",
            "0,1", "1,1", "2,1"];

`grid[2+1*3]` == `grid[5]` // 2+1*3=5
 grid[5] = "2,1"
```

I hope it will clear your doubt.